# Run javascript function on specific URL dir (htaccess)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, .htaccess

I have menu and there are some modal windows on my site that are hidden on default and appear when I click on particular menu item (simple .show() jquery function). Is it possible to use htaccess like this:

> Default site URL: www.example.com
>
> Menu 1 visible (function called) when URL: www.example.com/menu1/

So when there is subdirectory (not query string) in URL particular function is called. Is is possible at all?

Sorry for english.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - How do I ask a good question? - you should read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a solution just with php and .htaccess thanks to idea from miny1997.

index.php:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['menu']))
    {
        switch ($_GET['menu'])
        {
            case 'menu1':
                // jquery script 1
                break;
            case 'menu2':
                // jquery script 2
                break;
        }
    }
?>
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?menu=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use that PHP script to redirect users to another page(you can use GET-parameters and a if-query to let compile other content):

```
<?php
header('Location: http://www.example.com/#');
?>
```

And use that to run a function:

```
window.onload = function() {
if(window.location.hash) {
    //Run your JS code here
}
}
```

IMPORTANT: The hashtag indicates the redirect

Comment: Thanks for idea. I improved it a little bit - see my answer.

Comment: Nice work! I can't write in mod_rewrite, but I can understand the idea you have.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use htaccess to alter the content of a page, but you can achieve what you're asking about with javascript. You can use the `window.location` variable to determine what subdirectory the page is in (see here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-and-url-parts-in-javascript/ for more info).

Then you can control whether to use .show() function with basic simple `if` blocks.

Comment: But I have single page web (index.php) and when there is subdirectory in URL, 404 error appear. I need to redirect these subdirectories into base URL and call specific function.

Comment: In javascript, doesn't matter what happens in server. As far as it's concerned, if URL displays as directory, the code should be fine.